# I don't know how to write the average grade with variables

Tags: c++

I'm trying to automatically set the number of the given variables, for example:

```
char subject1[30];
char subject2[30];
char subject3[30];
float grade1;
float grade2;
float grade3;

cout << "Type in your first subject: "  ;
cin >> subject1;
cout << "Type in your second subject: ";
cin >> subject2;
cout << "Type in your third subject: ";
cin >> subject3;

cout << "Type in your grade for: " << subject1 << " :";
cin >> grade1;
cout << "Type in your grade for: " << subject2 << " :";
cin >> grade2;
cout << "Type in your grade for: " << subject3 << " :";
cin >> grade3;


float sum = grade1 + grade2 + grade3;
float average = (sum / 3);


cout << "AVERAGE GRADE";
cout << "************************************" << endl;
cout << subject1 << grade1 << endl;
cout << subject2 << grade2 << endl;
cout << subject3 << grade3 << endl;
cout << "====================================" << endl;
cout << "Average: " << average << endl;

return 0;
```

The code that calculates it works but I was wondering as how do I put the 3 grades that user inputed. So I  don't have to go edit the calculation part every time I add another subject. I'm not sure if I explained well as to what I meant but I hope you understand.

Comment: You're likely looking for either arrays or some sort of dynamically allocated containers such as `std::vector` to hold the subject/grade info in a better way or one that can be specified at runtime. Additionally, loops can be used to reduce code duplication to work with previously mentioned containers. I'd recommend looking up those as they are core concepts to programming in pretty much any language.

Comment: And [<algorithm>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) might avoid manual loop.

Comment: @LemonDrop Thank you very much for the feedback! Duly noted!

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to store everything in a `vector` (that's preferred most of the time over the `char array` you used) an then just loop for the amount of subjects you have.

```
#include <vector>   // need to inlcude this to be able to use vector
#include <iostream>

const int numSubjects = 3;

std::vector<std::string> prefix{"first", "second", "third"};
std::vector<std::string> subjects(numSubjects);
std::vector<float> grades(numSubjects);

for(int i = 0; i < numSubjects; i++) {
    std::cout << "Type in your " << prefix[i] << " subject: ";
    std::cin >> subjects[i];
    std::cout << "Type in your grade for " << subjects[i] << ": ";
    std::cin >> grades[i];
}

//afterwards do the calculations
```

Note that I initialized the vectors with a size of `numSubjects` that way you can access and write to indices of the vector with the `[]` operator. If you don't initialize `vector` with a size then you can use `push_back()` to insert elements.

Comment: This is great! But the unfortunate thing is that I am still in the process of learning the syntax and don't fully understand the code you wrote. Guess i should try doing something easier. Any suggestions on what i should do as a beginner then?

Comment: @AlenNikolaus Don't worry it's not as complicated as it might look. Depending on how accustomed you're already with datastructures you could look at the documentation for [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/). Just play around with it a little and see what you can do. Also if there is anything in particular that is unclear just let me know and maybe I can give better directions.

Comment: Well the "int i" is confusing me. Not really sure what it is, and google doesnt really help either

Comment: `int` is just the standard whole number type. In your original program you have used `float` which is a floating point type. So for the grade you have correctly used `float` as grades are not always whole numbers and can have a decimal part. For things that can and will always be whole numbers like the index in the loop you typically use `int`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "you can access and write to indices of the vector with the [] operator". Where do I use the [] operator?

Comment: Phew ok so after meddling around and checking and googling. I got everything to work with your code. I also did a mistake where I put grades and subjects as 1, 2, and 3 instead of 0, 1 and 2 because i didnt know c++ works like that.

Comment: Great to hear @AlenNikolaus. Playing around with things and trying to make stuff work is a good way to learn.